# Django Oracle cursor call external database view

Tags: django, oracle, database-cursor

I established a connection from my Django's project to external a Oracle database, connection it's done successfully and I can call store procedures or functions correctly like this:

```
days = cursor.callfunc('VAC_DICT', cx_Oracle.NUMBER, (identification,))
result = cursor.callproc('PINS_VAC', [data.get('identification'),'true'])
```

Thing is, I need to call a database view there called 'VAC_HIST', but when I try it this way:

```
periods = cursor.execute('VAC_HIST')
```

It gets me **"django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"**, got it, make sense that Im not using the correct syntax, but I searched a lot and can't find how to use cursor. something to call views, like "cursor.callview" or other....

Any idea how or what am I missing ?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an SQL statement in your case like the below

You can refer the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/)

```
 periods = cursor.execute('SELECT periods FROM VAC_HIST WHERE 
 cond=%s',string1);
```

Comment: I knew it was simple, works like a charm, Thanks !!

Comment: Or, for better performance on Oracle databases, you can use bind variables:

`periods = cursor.execute( 'SELECT periods FROM VAC_HIST WHERE cond = :condition', ['aCondition'] )`